# Is it possible to use integral2 /integral3 for piecewise constant function?

Tags: matlab, integral

I have defined the following parameters:

```
sigma=@(u)0.2.*((0<=u) && (u<1))+0.3.*((1<=u) && (u<2));
alpha=@(u)0.1.*((0<=u) && (u<1))+0.4.*((1<=u) && (u<2));
lambda=3;

if lambda==0
    E1Integrand=@(T,u,a)...
    (-1.*(T-u).*exp(-1.*lambda.*(T-u))).^2.*...
    (-1.*(T-a).*exp(-1.*lambda.*(T-a))).*...
    sigma(u).^2.*alpha(a).*sigma(a);
else
    E1Integrand=@(T,u,a)...
    ((1-exp(-1.*lambda.*(T-u)))./lambda).^2.*...
    ((1-exp(-1.*lambda.*(T-a)))./lambda).*...
    sigma(u).^2.*alpha(a).*sigma(a);
end
E1Integrand_amax=@(u)u;
E1Integral=integral2(NewE1Integrand,0,1.5,0,E1Integrand_amax);
```

I want to do double integral for a piecewise constant function. However, the following error message occurs:

```
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
Error in @(u)0.2.*((0<=u)&&(u<1))+0.3.*((1<=u)&&(u<2))
Error in
@(T,u,a)((1-exp(-1.*lambda.*(T-u)))./lambda).^2.*((1-exp(-1.*lambda.*(T-
a)))./lambda).*sigma(u).^2.*alpha(a).*sigma(a)
Error in @(u,a)E1Integrand(0.2,u,a)
Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 228)
       Z = FUN(X,Y);  NFE = NFE + 1;
Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);
Error in integral2Calc (line 9)
[q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);
Error in integral2 (line 106)
Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
```

I wonder how to fix it, or `integral2` cannot use to integrate piecewise constant function.

Comment: A piecewise constant function is trivial to integrate. It is literally adding the area of several rectangles

Comment: I understand. If it is the case, do I need to define different function in different ranges and do integration and add them together? In general, the piecewise constant function is determined by user, which may have 10-100 parts. Should I need to define 100 function, doing integration and add them together?

Comment: Let me repeat more clearly: a peicewise constant function of value `y1` in the range `[x1 x2]` has are of `y1*(x2-x1)`. Do not use integrals. Just add up this values